# How do you import python modules with Slurm?

Tags: python-3.7, slurm

This is my shell script for sbatch:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH .....
#SBATCH .....
#SBATCH .....
module load python/3.7.1
srun python runcomb.py
```

Im running a python script on a HPC which uses SLURM. For some reason, even basic python modules aren't being imported:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combiner.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

How do I install this? pip is not installed on the system so I can't even do a pip install.

Comment: are you able to use numpy inside the login node?

Comment: Have you looked whether `numpy` was available as an env module (`module spider numpy` or `module avail numb`)

Comment: Ask your sysadmin for pip, install venv and you will have the permissions to install whatever package you want once the venv is activated. Then, on the top of your python script point the python executable for your venv python bin